# Cannot add multiple redirect URLs to Azure app

Tags: powershell, azure-authentication

I am trying to add redirect URLs to Azure Application. I know I can do this from Portal here:

[image: image.png]

I ran the below commands in Powershell to do the same:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app_id -ReplyUrls $Urls
```

But I got stuck with this error:

> Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication
> Code: Authentication_Unauthorized Message: User was not found.
> RequestId: redacted DateTimeStamp: Tue, 13
> Sep 2022 10:27:33 GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription:
> Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed At line:1 char:1

Is this possible from Powershell? If there is any query in Graph, that also helps. Any ideas!

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You must use the objectId of the app reg instead of the appid.

Comment: Tried with objectId too, getting same error:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if you have multiple tenants in your domain and when you connected to Azure AD without specifying **`Tenant-ID`**  in the command **`Connect-AzureAD`** .

You can find the **Tenant-ID** in the Portal like below:

[image]

***To resolve the error, make sure to connect with the Azure AD like below:***

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <your_tenant_Id>

$Urls = "https://jwt.ms","https://jwt.io"
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $app_object_id -ReplyUrls $Urls
```

**Response:**

[image]

**The Redirect URIs added successfully in the Azure Portal like below:**

[image]